# Issue in receiving a mail from SendGrid using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to reset the password using the `SendGrid` API in node js. here I get the response as expected in postman but didn't receive any mail to the targeted address. is anything I'm missing?

```
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

// finds the email already in DB 
const admin = await loginModel.findOne({ where: { email } });
    if (!admin) {
      const updated_response = setErrorResponseMsg(
        RESPONSE.NO_DATA_FOUND,
        "email"
      );
      return send(res, updated_response);
    }

    // forgot password stuff
    const secret = admin._id + process.env.TOKEN_KEY;
    const token = jwt.sign({ admin_id: admin._id, email }, secret, {
      expiresIn: "15m",
    });
    const link = `http://localhost:8000/api/admin/reset_password/${admin.id}/${token}`;

 const msg = {
      to: admin.email,
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM, 
      subject: "Reset Your Password",
      text: "click the link below to reset your password",
      html: `<h1><a href=${link}>click here</h1>`,
    };

    const data = await sgMail.send(msg);
    // return res.send(link);
    return res.send(data);
```

response

[image: i get the response like this]

in SendGrid I get like this
[image: send grid]

event history in SendGrid
[image]

I followed all the steps, still not receiving any mail